# glibc detected: double free or corruption(out) error in c++

Tags: c++

I'm writing in c++. I took 4 value from user but when I get last value I got this error. Now I'll get value from user, after a while I use function for it. So I wrote like this.

```
double* array1;
double* array2;

array1 = (double*) malloc(2);
array2 = (double*) malloc(2);

cout<< "enter value 1" << endl;
cin >> array1[1];
cout<< "enter value 2" << endl;
cin >> array1[2];
cout<< "enter value 3" << endl;
cin >> array2[1];
cout<< "enter value 4" << endl;
cin >> array2[2];

cout<< "program is over"<< endl;
```

my function calculate some values and return an array:

```
double* Class::function()
{
double array[2];

//calculate some values

return array;
}
```

In main I'll use this function like this:

```
array2 = function();
```

Comment: A) you are allocating 2 bytes for what seems to be an array of doubles. B) You are returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: This is C++ you should be using `new` to allocate the dynamic arrays, or better yet use an `std::vector<double>` instead.

Comment: Your `malloc()` allocates two bytes of memory. That is not enough to hold even a *single* `double`. (Should probably be `malloc( 2 * sizeof( double ) )`. Then you access a *third* double via `array1[2]` / `array2[2]`? (Array indices start with `[0]`...) Also, what Mgetz said...

Comment: Oh, and also: Error not reproducable with the code you posted.

Comment: Arrays in C++ are spelled `std::vector`. If you are taught any other way to make an array first, it must be a conspiracy by your teachers to make you less competitive in the marketplace

Comment: i changed it to vector<double> array1, but when i change function to vector<double> function() header says 'vector' does not a name type, so it doesn't recognize function in cpp file.

Comment: @user3126199 you need to include `<vector>`, also vector exists in `namespace std`  so you will either need to have a `using namespace std;` or return `std::vector<double>`